# How to transfer Test Cases from one TFS2010 server to another

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, tfs2010

We have two TFS servers, one we use for testing the output of our developers, and one we use for testing features in TFS. The main problem with this is that it means I have to create new test cases to test TFS functionality, on top of the ones I have to create for testing our product.

The ideal case would obviously be to use the same test cases that we have already written, as we tend to test manually first and then automate while we wait for the next piece of functionality to be written, so by the time we come to test a new way of automating tests, we've got the test cases written.

The second upside to this would obviously be that once we had written our proof of concept, we can transfer the automated tests back to the production server, and instantly having something useful, rather than just a proof of concept.

There are a few tools online for transferring test cases from one TFS server, but I don't know whether I should trust them. I tried one that was mentions on MSDN - [Test Case Migrator Plus](http://tcmimport.codeplex.com/) - however I can't seem to get it to work. I have also tried exporting test cases to an excel query, changing the  sheet's xml file within the xlsx file to change the server, and then publishing. This worked... To a degree. The test cases were there, but each one only had one step, with both the test steps and expected outcomes concatenated together.

It seems to me there must be some way of capturing the data before excel mangles it and sending it to the other server, but I'm really at a loss - I'm considering writing them in by hand, but that is obviously going to be a fairly large burden going forwards.

I can't imagine I'm the only one with this issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little puzzled as to why you have two separate TFS servers. What was the reasoning behind this?

That aside, your (or one of your developers) best route is to get to grips with the TFS API and code your way out of this situation. There are lots of examples for the API, [this is one](http://www.larswilhelmsen.com/2010/05/05/migrating-work-items-from-one-tfs-project-to-another/) that should get you started.

If your company are going to persist with this odd TFS setup, you might want to consider extending that code sample to run a scheduled sync between the two servers. The recommended solution would of course to use just one.